# C++ store pointer of element of container

Tags: c++, containers, smart-pointers

In  my application, I have a `std::list<TreeNode>` that is the owner of my tree nodes. Now I want to be able to access the left and right neighbor inside a TreeNode, so which smart pointer should I use to store the neighbors inside a TreeNode? The only pointer suitable for this is a raw pointer because a TreeNode is not the owner of its neighbors, so I hardly see how a smart pointer could be useful here.

Also, the TreeNodes have to be store in other containers for fast access (to have the highest-priority one), so I can't just store unique_ptr of neighbors, because I also need to store them in fast containers (priority_queue)

Comment: You are probably looking for `std::list<TreeNode>::iterator`. It lets you get the node's neighbors in constant time. I don't think any kind of pointer will be able to do what you are asking.

Comment: Does `TreeNode` somehow have pointers to its neighbors in the container?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux a raw pointer to the lists elements would achieve the same, no?

Comment: If the list owns the `TreeNode`s, then you don't want a smart pointer. Smart pointers establish ownership, and the `TreeNode`s are already owned.

Comment: Do you have a good reason not to use ```std::vector<TreeNodee>``` instead of a list?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 If you have a raw pointer to the Nth element in the list, how do you get N+1 and N-1 from a raw pointer? The raw pointer does not give access to any implementation details of `std::list`, so you can't get any kind of `next` or `prev` pointer. And since this is a `list` (non-contiguous storage) you can't simply increment or decrement the pointer.

Comment: May I ask why using an std::vector + index isn't an option? std::list is rarely a good choice when you are looking for performance.

Comment: There are ways to implement trees on top a flat arrays, they provide substantially better performance. There is a linear relationship between the parent index and child index, this approach also happens to solve some of your other issues. The tree would then a view on top of the array.

Comment: @user4581301 So if the list is already the owner, how can I store pointers to elements in the list without using raw pointers? In other words, how are smart pointers relevant if I only need raw pointers?

Comment: @Jojolatino *"how are smart pointers relevant"*  They are not relevant in this case.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux But I want to use smart pointers because they are the way to go in modern C++

Comment: `std::list` has much more forgiving iterator invalidation rules. As nodes are added to a `std::vector`, the vector will be resized and all of the existing pointers used by the various nodes will be blown to hell and beyond

Comment: @Jojolatino That is not correct. Smart pointers are replacement for raw pointer *when the pointer represents ownership*. In simple terms, an owning pointer is a pointer that will eventually or may eventually be used to `delete` a `new`ed object. If this isn't the case, raw pointers are fine. Raw pointers are still a tool that is fine for certain jobs, its just that they aren't the tool for *every* job anymore. But neither of these solutions work for what you want to do. Use the container's iterator. It is designed to solve the problem you are asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so which (smart) pointer should I use to store the neighbors inside a TreeNode?

You should use a suitable pointer type.

> The only pointer suitable for this is a raw pointer

Well, there you go. If the raw pointer is the only suitable one, then using an unsuitable smart pointer would be counter-productive.

---

If you have trouble establishing correct lifetime for the nodes, then shared ownership is something that may be considered. An easy choice is to use shared pointers throughout. If you instead want to keep the ownership primarily in a list, then you could use weak pointers elsewhere.

---

> But I want to use smart pointers because they are the way to go in modern C++

You've misunderstood the point of smart pointers.

Comment: But am I forced to have a `std::list<shared_ptr<TreeNode>>` instead of `std::list<TreeNode>`, so I can have `weak_ptr<TreeNode` for everyone else that want to refer to an element?

Comment: @Jojolatino You'll have to expand on why you want to put yourself through that hell. It seems like you're adding complexity in the name of an overly rigid interpretation of a guideline intended to make your life easier.

Comment: @Jojolatino `am I forced to have a std::list<shared_ptr<TreeNode>>` If you need shared ownership, which is required for weak pointers, then yes you are. If you don't need shared owenrship, then you aren't forced to use shared pointers.